# Delete partition on OSX 10.6 without wiping the entire disk

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, partitioning

When I got my MacBook Pr I partitioned the HDD to install Windows via Bootcamp later. Now I wanted to do this. But it seems like I have to partition it using the Bootcamp installer.

Now I'd like to remove the Windows partition from the disk without losing the Mac one. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you start `/Applications/Utilities/Boot Camp Assistant`, you should be able to select your Windows partition for removal. Your Mac OS X partition will be automatically resized to use the then unused disk space. This will **not** remove your Mac OS X partition. This is how I did it a while ago, IIRC.

---

I don't have two partitions on my Macs at the moment, but when you select the *disk* in `/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility`, and select the *Partition* tab, can't you select the Boot Camp/Windows partition, click the `–` button to remove it, and increase the size of your Mac partition afterwards? It should look a bit like this:

[image]

---

If you cannot select the Windows partition for formatting, make sure it's not configured as the startup disk.

Comment: When starting the Bootcamp Assistant it says something like "start volume can't be partitioned nor recovered from single partition" in german.

Comment: @dantz Did you actually install windows in the second partition? Is it formatted? What's the actual message (in German)? Which is your startup disk (in System Preferences)?

Comment: No it wasn't formatted. After changing that it was no problem. Thanks. If you submit this as a solution I can accept it as the solution for this topic.

Comment: @dantz Edited (I assume you needed to change the startup disk).